# React Hooks: Is there a way to calculate state values based on another state value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm looking for a way to calculate state values which depend on other state values using React Hooks.

I'm familiarizing myself with React Hooks. So far I've been using useState and useEffect. I'm aware of other hooks e.g. useReduce, useCallback, etc.

I've made a simple rates calculator that converts rates on hourly, weekly, monthly, and yearly basis. When I change the respective rate other rates will be updated accordingly.

**The code for the app as follows:**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
    CssBaseline,
    Container,
    Typography,
    TextField
} from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    paper: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(8), // = 4 * 2
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
}));

function App() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [hourlyRate, setHourlyRate] = useState(10);
    const [workHour, setWorkHour] = useState(40);
    const [weeklyRate, setWeeklyRate] = useState(400);
    const [monthlyRate, setMonthlyRate] = useState(1600);
    const [yearlyRate, setYearlyRate] = useState(19200);

    const tryConvert = ({ name, value }) => {
        if (name === 'work-hours') {
            setWorkHour(value);
            setWeeklyRate(value * hourlyRate);
            setMonthlyRate(value * hourlyRate * 4);
            setYearlyRate(value * hourlyRate * 4 * 12);
        } else if (name === 'hourly-rate') {
            setHourlyRate(value);
            setWeeklyRate(value * workHour);
            setMonthlyRate(value * workHour * 4);
            setYearlyRate(value * workHour * 4 * 12);
        } else if (name === 'weekly-rate') {
            setWeeklyRate(value);
            setHourlyRate(value / workHour);
            setMonthlyRate(value * 4);
            setYearlyRate(value * 4 * 12);
        } else if (name === 'monthly-rate') {
            setMonthlyRate(value);
            setWeeklyRate(value / 4);
            setHourlyRate(value / workHour / 4);
            setYearlyRate(value * 12);
        } else if (name === 'yearly-rate') {
            setYearlyRate(value);
            setMonthlyRate(value / 12);
            setWeeklyRate(value / 12 / 4);
            setHourlyRate(value / 12 / 4 / workHour);
        }
    };

    return (
        <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
            <CssBaseline />
            <div className={classes.paper}>
                <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                    Rate Kalkulator
                </Typography>
                <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    id="hourly-rate"
                    label="Hourly Rate"
                    name="hourly-rate"
                    autoFocus
                    inputProps={{ 'data-testid': 'hourly-rate' }}
                    value={hourlyRate ? hourlyRate : 0}
                    onChange={event => tryConvert(event.target)}
                />
                <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    id="work-hours"
                    label="Work Hours"
                    name="work-hours"
                    inputProps={{ 'data-testid': 'work-hours' }}
                    value={workHour}
                    onChange={event => tryConvert(event.target)}
                />
                <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    id="weekly-rate"
                    label="Weekly Rate"
                    name="weekly-rate"
                    inputProps={{ 'data-testid': 'weekly-rate' }}
                    value={weeklyRate ? weeklyRate : 0}
                    onChange={event => tryConvert(event.target)}
                />
                <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    id="monthly-rate"
                    label="Monthly Rate"
                    name="monthly-rate"
                    inputProps={{ 'data-testid': 'monthly-rate' }}
                    value={monthlyRate ? monthlyRate : 0}
                    onChange={event => tryConvert(event.target)}
                />
                <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    id="yearly-rate"
                    label="Yearly Rate"
                    name="yearly-rate"
                    inputProps={{ 'data-testid': 'yearly-rate' }}
                    value={yearlyRate ? yearlyRate : 0}
                    onChange={event => tryConvert(event.target)}
                />
            </div>
        </Container>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**Codesandbox Link - `tryConvert`**

[Rate Kalkulator - tryConvert](https://codesandbox.io/embed/rate-kalkulator-p0x6d?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js)

*The app worked as expected, as far as I've tested, haven't worked on the edge cases yet.*

**Simplifying Rate Conversion**

I'm trying to simplify the conversion `tryConvert` with other React Hooks but haven't been successful. This is the code for the conversion from the codes above :

```js
    const tryConvert = ({ name, value }) => {
        if (name === 'work-hours') {
            setWorkHour(value);
            setWeeklyRate(value * hourlyRate);
            setMonthlyRate(value * hourlyRate * 4);
            setYearlyRate(value * hourlyRate * 4 * 12);
        } else if (name === 'hourly-rate') {
            setHourlyRate(value);
            setWeeklyRate(value * workHour);
            setMonthlyRate(value * workHour * 4);
            setYearlyRate(value * workHour * 4 * 12);
        } else if (name === 'weekly-rate') {
            setWeeklyRate(value);
            setHourlyRate(value / workHour);
            setMonthlyRate(value * 4);
            setYearlyRate(value * 4 * 12);
        } else if (name === 'monthly-rate') {
            setMonthlyRate(value);
            setWeeklyRate(value / 4);
            setHourlyRate(value / workHour / 4);
            setYearlyRate(value * 12);
        } else if (name === 'yearly-rate') {
            setYearlyRate(value);
            setMonthlyRate(value / 12);
            setWeeklyRate(value / 12 / 4);
            setHourlyRate(value / 12 / 4 / workHour);
        }
    };
```

**My attempt on using useEffect**

What I've tried is using useEffect to add callbacks when the states are changed. The codes below illustrate what I've tried:

```js
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


    const [hourlyRate, setHourlyRate] = useState(10);
    const [workHour, setWorkHour] = useState(40);
    const [weeklyRate, setWeeklyRate] = useState(400);
    const [monthlyRate, setMonthlyRate] = useState(1600);
    const [yearlyRate, setYearlyRate] = useState(19200);

    useEffect(() => {
        setWeeklyRate(hourlyRate * workHour);
        setMonthlyRate(hourlyRate * workHour * 4);
        setYearlyRate(hourlyRate * workHour * 4 * 12);
    }, [hourlyRate, workHour]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setHourlyRate(weeklyRate / workHour);
        setMonthlyRate(weeklyRate * 4);
        setYearlyRate(weeklyRate * 4 * 12);
    }, [weeklyRate, workHour]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setHourlyRate(monthlyRate / 4 / workHour);
        setWeeklyRate(monthlyRate / 4);
        setYearlyRate(monthlyRate * 12);
    }, [monthlyRate, workHour]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setHourlyRate(yearlyRate / 12 / 4 / workHour);
        setWeeklyRate(yearlyRate / 12 / 4);
        setMonthlyRate(yearlyRate / 12);
    }, [yearlyRate, workHour]);
```

If I use this approach, when I change `workHour` the conversion would not work as expected. I think it is because the `workHour` has become dependency on the 4 different `useEffect`. I'm still not sure about this.

**Codesandbox Link - useEffect**

[Rate Kalkulator - useEffect](https://codesandbox.io/s/rate-kalkulator-db6u6?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js)

*if you change the work hour the conversion won't work*

---

Currently, I'm trying other approaches using useReduce, but I'm still not sure if this would be the best way to convert the rates.

What would be the best way to simplify my tryConvert?

I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is? Taking a look at you sandbox, the conversions appear to work as expected. Are you just trying to integrate useEffect?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo The current conversion work by using `tryConvert` function. I'm trying to change how to do it with other React Hooks, e.g. `useEffect`. However when I make `useEffect` callbacks for each of the state the conversion doesn't work on workHour. I'll try to put up a codesandbox demonstrating this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's really no need for `useEffect` here. `useEffect` is for side effects (e.g. `setInterval`, `document.title`, things that aren't part of the render cycle).

Your first solution works fine, but you can simplify it by having a single source of truth for the rate, and calculating the other rates based on that one. Something like this:

```
function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [hourlyRate, setHourlyRate] = useState(10);
  const [workHour, setWorkHour] = useState(40);

  const convertTo = name => {
    const map = {
      weekly: hourlyRate * workHour,
      monthly: hourlyRate * workHour * 4,
      yearly: hourlyRate * workHour * 52
    };
    return map[name] || 0;
  };

  const convertFrom = name => e => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    const map = {
      weekly: value / workHour,
      monthly: value / workHour / 4,
      yearly: value / workHour / 52
    };
    setHourlyRate(map[name]);
  };

  return (
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Rate Kalkulator
        </Typography>
        <TextField
          label="Hourly Rate"
          value={hourlyRate || 0}
          onChange={e => setHourlyRate(e.target.value)}
        />
        <TextField
          label="Work Hours"
          value={workHour}
          onChange={e => setWorkHour(e.target.value)}
        />
        <TextField
          label="Weekly Rate"
          value={convertTo("weekly") || 0}
          onChange={convertFrom("weekly")}
        />
        <TextField
          label="Monthly Rate"
          value={convertTo("monthly") || 0}
          onChange={convertFrom("monthly")}
        />
        <TextField
          label="Yearly Rate"
          value={convertTo("yearly") || 0}
          onChange={convertFrom("yearly")}
        />
      </div>
  );
}
```

For a working example, here's a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/rate-kalkulator-ej5m8

Comment: Awesome! thank you! I was thinking of making all the rates into states. But making one rate as a single source of truth would make sense.